# "Node Stack Overflow" error while running R script on Plumber

Tags: r, overflow, plumber

I am trying to create a REST web API using plumber package in R.first time it runs fine but second time when we run the same code it's showing the "node stack overflow" error. I just try to print the same message from my function. Code is given in the next section

I have also tried running it on VMWare linux (Ubuntu) by allocating it additional memory (initially 8192 kb and then 7969177 kb. However the result has always been the same error

```
    # plumber.R
    #' Echo the parameter that was sent in
    #' @param msg The message to echo back.
    #' @get /echo
       function(msg="")
        {
          list(msg = paste0 ("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
        }
       library('plumber')
      plumber::plumb("plumber.R")$run
```

Comment: Are the last two lines part of the file `plumber.R`? If yes, remove them and run them separately, either from the console or in a separate script. Otherwise there is infinite recursion

Comment: Hi .. Thanks for your response Aurèle. I tried it but the problem is still the same.

Comment: Also, missing parentheses after `run`, which is a function. `run()`. Though I don't see how that would cause overflow

Comment: Still no luck :-(

Comment: Same error? Can you describe in more details the steps to follow to reproduce the problem?

Comment: First I clear everything from console and Environment and then create a simple function, save that file as plumber.R. and then run that function by plumber::plumb("plumber.R")$run() line.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Has anyone resolved this?

Answer (score 1):

Create one file in R and name it myfile.R in a folder
create another file name it plumb.R
both file should be in same folder or working dir

for myfile.R
write this code

```
# myfile.R
#' @get /mean
#' 
normalMean <- function(samples=10){
  data <- rnorm(samples)
  mean(data)
}
```

In plumb.R write

```
library(plumber)

r <- plumb("myfile.R")
r$run(port=8000)
```

After that open your google browser and type as follows
http://localhost:8000/mean

Simple it will give you output

Answer (score 0):

remove the first line "# plumber" and every thing will work perfectly.